# Youtube videos not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I need display youtube videos when click an image, it displays youtube videos as new popup.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="youtubepopup.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({ autoplay: 0 });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYSpIz2FjU" title="jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin TEST">Test Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

when click an image it didn't change anything.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Where is `#imageID` image?

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/8MXZa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/jquery.youtubepopup.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("img.youtube").YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id' ,'clickOutsideClose': true,});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="4eYSpIz2FjU" class="youtube" title="..." src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/4eYSpIz2FjU/1.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2zcxP/3/)